# How to update a cell value by code?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have a `CellWidget` (`EditTextCell`) that I want to set a specific value manually by code. But the UI is not updated when I use the following code? What am I missing?

```
@UiField(provided = true)
CellWidget<String> cell;

cell.setValue(text, true);
cell.redraw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, as I found a workaround:

```
    ((EditTextCell) cell.getCell()).clearViewData(KEY_PROVIDER.getKey(text));
    cell.getCell().setValue(new Context(0, 0, KEY_PROVIDER.getKey(text)), cell.getElement(), text);
    cell.setValue(text, true, true);
```

Don't know if this is the proper way to force an update on a single cellwidget textcell, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to update a specific cell in a `CellTable`? In that case, I'm not sure your solution will work. If you just want to refresh data in a table, then you should use a `DataProvider`, then just change that and the UI should change too. If you want to table to respond to user events (such as clicking on a cell), you should look into [handling Cell events](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells#cell-onBrowserEvent) instead.